# Any way to automatically merge approved nonconflicting Gitorious merge request?

Tags: git, merge, gitorious

We are using [Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Home), installed on a local server to host our shared git repositories.

When a developer sends a merge request from his public clone to main repository, the owner/integrator/architect has to pull the request into his local git repo, merge and then push it back up to gitorious hosted main repository.

This is normal for larger merges and especially when conflicts occur.

But for minor changes that has no conflicts it would be nice to just approve and merge inside the gitorious interface or similar, without involving external(local) repositories. Especially if there is a large team with many minor merge requests...

Is there anyway we can implement this?

I see Github has recently [developed something similar](https://github.com/blog/843-the-merge-button).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Gitorious blog tags on "Merge Request"](http://blog.gitorious.org/tag/merge-requests/), this doesn't seem to be implemented.